# How to export rules in Outlook with destination folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I exported rules from my friends Outlook and created a folder structure similar to his.

But when I tried to import the rules, all the rules failed . When I checked the rules does not contain the destination folder. So if I click each rule and select `specified folder` to choose the destination the error is removed.

There are hundreds of rule to be imported. It is not possible to manually specify folder names for each rule. Is it possible to export rules with the file name ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't without using third-party tools or writing custom VBA script, program or Outlook add-in by yourself.

Comment: How about a link to a solution?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, you can easily Google third-party tools.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon not only should you link to an answer but transpose the link in case it becomes dead

Comment: If I could vote -2 for not even offering a link I would